# A switch-case workflow in Kanban?

Tags: kanban

Does Kanban support switch-case workflows?

The example is a code review - it can be performed by either our team's developer or another team's developer. If we need to make any change in another team's repository, then a code review will be performed by another team's developer. And it can be quite complicated because we need to conform to another team's requirements and all we can do is to wait for when the other team do this review - this is a very different process.

So we have branching: after DEVELOPMENT the issue goes either to INTERNAL CODE REVIEW or EXTERNAL CODE REVIEW.

The more complex workflow may contain more bracnhes.

Answer (score 2):

In Kanban, we want to visualize whatever the workflow is, so if that is your workflow, that is what you should represent.

That said, there is another part of this answer. Kanban asks us to manage the work, not the people. Therefore, in your example, you would usually represent this work the same way regardless of if it is your team or another.

Comment: Quoting the OP: "need to conform to another team's requirements and all we can do is to wait". It's very hand to see the difference at a glance, an it's also a very different kind of work from being active and doing the work. Is that not something that suggest you second part is not directly applicable here?

Comment: Potentially. If there are two different processes and you can go down one path or another, it may make sense to represent that in the visualization because the way the work is done is different. However, in the description, it looks like there is a code review step that may be done either internally or externally and that decision may also influence code standards or how we do other steps, but the steps in the process are the same regardless. In short, I don't know what value, for a systems thinking perspective, you get from visualizing that branching path.